# android - Is there a way to cache a View?

Tags: android, listview, caching, view

I have a complex listview. Every item in this listview has three EditTexts and two Checkboxes. Outside the listview is a Button for adding rows to the listview, one for continue and one to go back.

Continue and Back does both call something like:

```
setContentView(R.layout.stepX);
```

**The problem:**
If you press continue and then go back all items from the listview are empty. Is there a easy way to save the input or hold him in ram?

My current workaround is to create a Class for a listitem and if you continue every itemdata is read and saved to an arraylist. If you go back it read the arraylist and rebuild the listitems.

Comment: "Is there a easy way to save the input or hold him in ram?" -- yes. Don't call `setContentView()`. Instead, do something else to implement your "continue" and "back" logic. For example, use fragments, hiding and showing fragments as needed.

Comment: what do you want do when pressing continue or back?

Comment: @陈志帆 i want to set another view. It is nearly the same process like a installation of a programm on windows. With continue you get to the next step and with back you get one step back.